# Hide order items column name in WooCommerce admin

Tags: css, woocommerce, orders

I'm trying to hide the columns in the administrative part of Woocomerce. With the following code I have not succeeded and I am stuck and my question is:

How can I hide the name of the columns in the administrative part (order items)?
The fields that i would like to hide is line_cost and line_tax .

```
add_action( 'admin_head', 'admin_head_shop_order_inline_Cust' );

function admin_head_shop_order_inline_css_S() {
    global $pagenow, $typenow;

    // Targeting WooCommerce admin single orders
    if ( in_array( $pagenow, ['post.php', 'post-new.php'] ) && $typenow === 'shop_order' ) :
    ?><style>
    
    table.woocommerce_order_items .item_cost .view   {display:none;} 
    table.woocommerce_order_items .item_cost .sortable {display:none;}
 
    </style><?php
    endif;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to hide them by CSS then you're near to the right code... This works for me, it hides the header and the column as well.

```php
add_action('admin_head', 'admin_head_shop_order_inline_css');

function admin_head_shop_order_inline_css()
{
    global $pagenow, $typenow;

    // Targeting WooCommerce admin single orders
    if (in_array($pagenow, ['post.php', 'post-new.php']) && $typenow === 'shop_order') :
    ?>
        <style>
            table.woocommerce_order_items .item_cost { display: none; }
            table.woocommerce_order_items .line_tax { display: none }
        </style>
    <?php
    endif;
}
```